# How to install Qt-Creator 2.5.2 in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, qt-creator

I am using Ubuntu MATE. I have installed Qt Creator 3.5.1 on my system but I want to install Qt Creator **version 2.5.2**. How can I install it?

Comment: What release of Ubuntu-MATE?  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=qtcreator shows you want a very old version)

Comment: Yes @guiverc, I want old version of Qt-Creator (Version 2.5.2). I am using Ubuntu-Mate Version 1.16.2

Comment: Ubuntu-MATE releases are *yy.mm*, MATE 1.16 (the desktop) was released late in 2016-Sept, and was used in Ubuntu-MATE 16.10.  Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 LTS (the oldest still supported) uses 1.20.1; what release of Ubuntu-MATE? as Ubuntu-MATE 16.10 is well-past EOL & thus off-topic.

Comment: @guiverc I have Ubuntu 16.04 also.. i have tried in it but couldn't installed.

Comment: What is the real reason to have Qt Creator 2.5.2 from Ubuntu 12.10 (currenlty EOL)? Modern version of Qt Creator also supports Qt 4.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to install [`qtcreator` version `2.5.2-0ubuntu1` from Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal)](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtcreator/qtcreator_2.5.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) which is EOL (will not get security updates for its packages).
But it will not work because of version problems of corresponding `qt4-qmake`.

So I'll suggest to use modern Qt Creator from your Ubuntu version to build Qt projects.
To setup it for Qt4 your need to install the needed packages:

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator qt4-qmake qt4-default qt4-qmlviewer
```

For Qt5 you need also install the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

Answer (score 0):

For fresh installation of qt creator, try:

```
sudo apt update
```

Install build essential and manpages-dev

```
sudo apt install build-essential manpages-dev
```

To install required version of GCC versions

```
sudo apt install gcc-8 g++-8 gcc-9 g++-9 gcc-10 g++-10
```

Now install qtcreator (it may take some time depending on the internet connection)

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator
```

Get some recomended library (optional)

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

and if you already tried to install qt but installation is failed then
try following:

Firstly need to remove old installed files which didn't find linker and cause error

```
sudo apt-get remove qtcreator
sudo apt-get autoremove qtcreator
```

then follow the above described installation commands.